# Equivalent for CSS property hidden in QT

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt5

I would like to know how I achieve an effect like [overflow: hidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) in Qt5.

In essence I want to create an infinite scroll Area similar to [QScrollArea](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qscrollarea.html) for a special case but am unable to archive this using `setStyleSheet` my class `QInfiniteScrollWidget` that is inheriting from `QWidget`.

I am trying to display an extremely huge amount (>1e5) of entries from a database. I am fetching only the entries relevant to the displayed area, and have for each of their types (think of them as PDFs, photos, music or videos) an individual widget type that displays them, possibly playing videos or music, cropping or rotating the images, splitting the PDFs. Some of these actions are written back to the database, so the number of items could change. Some change their size during interaction, like cropped images.
I want to be able to jump into each area of my database using a scrollbar or scroll entry by entry.

So I wanted to take a `QWidget` subclass `QInfiniteScrollWidget` , make a 2-3 times larger `QWidget` (blue area) visible in a view-port (dotted box) in the `QInfiniteScrollWidget` and control the part of the larger widget shown in the view-port by the `QScrollBar`. Then I could shuffle children from the top of the larger widget to the bottom (and change what they display in the process) when the value of the scroll bar changes to create an [infinite scroll](https://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/infinite_scrolling.html) widget.

(Image taken from a browser.)
[image]

This is how my current QT-App looks like:

[image]

I would like to have it look like a `QScrollArea`:
[image]

The reason why my current `QInfiniteScrollWidget` does not work is that it forces the whole large `QWidget` (blue area in the browser image) into the view-port (dotted box in the browser image). I want the large `QWidget` to behave similar to the paragraph in the browser  and overflow its parent while being hidden outside of the view-port.

Then I could set the position of the large `QWidget` relative to the view-port according to the local scroll progress and keep some widgets above and below the dotted box ready to be shown as soon as the user scrolls.

Here is my actual code:

```
class QInfiniteScrollWidget(QtWidgets.QFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(300, 400))
        self.scroll_bar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(self)
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("overflow: hidden;")
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.widget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.scroll_bar)
        self.widget_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.widgets = [QtWidgets.QLabel(self.widget) for _ in range(36)]
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets):
            widget.setText("Test text %i" % i)
            widget.setStyleSheet("border:1px solid gray;")
            self.widget_layout.addWidget(widget)
```

PS: I already tried to use `QTableView` and its friends, but they do not work for various reasons. The biggest problem was that my child widgets contain dynamically created controls and triggering each of their connected actions by back-calculating the targeted control from coordinates to that the delegate did draw sounds like an epic undertaking.

PPS: Please excuse the unclear question.

Edit Here the code implementing @Atmos answer:

```
import sys
import typing

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractListModel, QModelIndex, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QRegion
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QStyledItemDelegate, QStyleOptionViewItem, QAbstractItemView


class TestWidget(QtWidgets.QFrame):

    def __init__(self, row: int, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.row = None
        self.click_memory = {}
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.label_1.setText("Click Me")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_1.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    def update_row(self, row: int) -> None:
        self.row = row
        self.label_2.setText(("%i Clicked." if self.row in self.click_memory else "%i Not clicked yet.") % row)

    def button_clicked(self):
        self.click_memory[self.row] = True
        self.label_2.setText("%i Clicked." % (self.row or 0))


class TestModel(QAbstractListModel):

    def rowCount(self, parent: QModelIndex = ...) -> int:
        return 12

    def flags(self, index: QModelIndex) -> QtCore.Qt.ItemFlags:
        return super().flags(index) | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable

    def data(self, index: QModelIndex, role: int = 0) -> typing.Any:
        return str(index.row())


class TestDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.widget = TestWidget(0, None)

    def sizeHint(self, option: QStyleOptionViewItem, index: QtCore.QModelIndex) -> QtCore.QSize:
        return QtCore.QSize(self.widget.sizeHint())

    def paint(self, painter: QtGui.QPainter, option: QStyleOptionViewItem, index: QtCore.QModelIndex):
        painter.save()
        self.widget.update_row(index.row())
        self.widget.resize(option.rect.size())
        painter.translate(option.rect.topLeft())
        self.widget.render(painter, QPoint(), QRegion(), QtWidgets.QWidget.DrawChildren)
        painter.restore()

    def createEditor(self, parent: QtWidgets.QWidget, option: QStyleOptionViewItem, index: QModelIndex):
        widget = self.widget
        widget.setFixedSize(self.widget.size())
        self.widget.update_row(index.row())
        self.widget.setParent(parent)
        self.widget = TestWidget(0, None)
        self.widget.click_memory = widget.click_memory
        return widget


class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.main_widget = QtWidgets.QListView(self)
        self.main_widget.setModel(TestModel())
        self.main_widget.setItemDelegate(TestDelegate(self.main_widget))
        self.main_widget.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        self.show()

    @classmethod
    def start_gui(cls, args):
        app = QApplication(args)
        ex = App()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    App.start_gui(sys.argv)
```

Comment: I have failed to understand, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Honestly, I do not even know how you managed to make your application look like your first screenshot... what is your code? Why don't you simply post screenshots of your application instead of screenshots of a webpage that is in no way related to it? And again what are you trying to do? FYI, I actually had to read your question 3 times before I understood you mistyped "archive" instead of "achieve"; you are waaaaaay less clear for others than you think you are, this typo is just an example.

Comment: @msebas Sorry but your question is extremely confusing. If you want to hide the vertical scroll bar of a scroll area, just use [`setVerticalScrollBarPolicy()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#verticalScrollBarPolicy-prop) with `ScrollBarAlwaysOff`. Still, it's completely unclear what this has to do with an "infinite" scroll area, so, please take your time and try to rephrase your question. Remember that *we are not you*: you can't expect us to understand a concept based on vague or partial information: put yourself in our shoes and imagine we know *nothing* about your needs.

Comment: Well, I have 2 Test applications. The first one is just a widget with a set of several Labels, so I did not see any benefit in posting it. The second one is related to you answer, so I hesitated to post it in the question, but if you insist I could do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

If you do not add a widget to the layout of your widget you can move it around as you please, which is effectively an `overflow: hidden`, as soon as you move the widget to a position where only a part of the widget is visible.
Be aware that in this case one has to manage anything the layout normally takes care of by ones own source.

Long answer:

Well, right way to the solution is like most of the time to just read more source.

In this case one only need to study how exactly `QAbstractScrollArea` and `QScrollArea` are implemented, see [ref](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractscrollarea.cpp.html) and [ref](https://codebrowser.dev/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qscrollarea.cpp.html), thanks to Atmo for pointing me to correct classes.

Reading the source files of both classes I found that no layout is applied to the widget that displays the real contents. Instead its size and other properties are managed directly. The `QScrollArea`s `updateWidgetPosition` method then moves it accordingly to where it should be.

My final test code reads as

```
class TestWidget(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    def __init__(self, row: int, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.row = row
        self.click_memory = {}
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.label_1.setText("Click Me")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_1.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)

    def update_row(self, row: int) -> None:
        self.row = row
        self.label_2.setText(("%i Clicked." if self.row in self.click_memory else "%i Not clicked yet.") % row)

    def button_clicked(self):
        self.click_memory[self.row] = True
        self.label_2.setText("%i Clicked." % (self.row or 0))


class QInfiniteScrollWidget(QAbstractScrollArea):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.global_click_memory = {}
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.widgets = [TestWidget(i, self.widget) for i in range(24)]
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets):
            widget.update_row(i)
            widget.click_memory = self.global_click_memory
            self.layout.addWidget(widget)

    def viewportEvent(self, a0: QtCore.QEvent) -> bool:
        area_size = self.viewport().size()
        widget_size = self.widget.size()

        self.verticalScrollBar().setPageStep(area_size.height() // self.widgets[0].height() * 5)
        self.horizontalScrollBar().setPageStep(area_size.width())
        self.verticalScrollBar().setRange(0, 5 * int(1e5))
        self.horizontalScrollBar().setRange(0, widget_size.width() - area_size.width())
        self.updateWidgetPosition()
        return True

    def scrollContentsBy(self, dx: int, dy: int) -> None:
        self.updateWidgetPosition()

    def updateWidgetPosition(self):
        v_value = self.verticalScrollBar().value() * self.widgets[0].height() / 5
        first_widget = int(self.verticalScrollBar().value() / 5 / 24 * 24)
        for i, widget in enumerate(self.widgets):
            widget.update_row(i + first_widget)
        h_value, top_left = self.horizontalScrollBar().value(), self.viewport().rect().topLeft()
        self.widget.move(top_left.x() - h_value, top_left.y() - int(v_value) % self.widget.height())
```

which has many problems like empty areas and not the correct numbers rendered in many places. I leave fixing this to the interested reader, it should only be related to calculating the new position.

Answer (score 1):

An infinite scrolling is basically a finite scrolling where elements are added if it gets low enough. Hiding the scrollbar hides to the user the fact you are reaching the bottom.

`QAbstractScrollArea` (see [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html)) is the class that has methods to make scrollbars disappear; it has nothing to do with Qt's stylesheets:

```
myWidget.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
myWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
```

It is of course applicable to all the subclasses of `QAbstractScrollArea`, including `QScrollArea`, `QAbstractItemView`... I believe `QListView` would be the most sensible choice for you. Consider `QTableView` if you want to maintain columns.

In your case, what I think would be the most simple is:

1. Use a `QListView` with a custom model.
   Since it is a subclass of `QAbstractScrollArea`, you can hide the scrollbar(s).
2. Implement an item delegate (subclass of `QStyledItemDelegate`) in charge of representing the every item.
   Remember a delegate can be made of any widget you want, including a widget containing other widgets and it will allow you to reuse the 1 edition widget for all items, as opposed to creating multiple copies.
   Override the `sizeHint` method of your delegate to control how much space each row takes. If possible, make it so each line takes the same space and use the `setUniformItemSizes` of the `QListView` to optimize performance of your program, especially on many items.
3. Create your subclass of `QAbstractItemModel` (or the convenience class `QAbstractListModel`) to contain the data.
   Importantly, models have the `canFetchMore` and `fetchMore` methods, that you can use to populate new rows into your model without having to care when it is needed (the view will take care of deciding when it must be called by itself).

Comment: Well, I need an infinite scrolling on both sides, so I have to remove Items on top if the scrolling gets low enough and add them again if the view is scrolled back up. 

I need a scrollbar to be able to navigate to random areas, I wand to hide the parts of the large inner widget that should not be shown in the viewport of my `QInfiniteScrollWidget`.

You are right that `QAbstractScrollArea` might be a better parent than `QWidget`.

[QStyledItemDelegate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstyleditemdelegate.html) only has a `paint` method. Could you please explain how I return a widget with it?

Comment: Despite me asking for more details in 2 comments, you had put no indication you needed infinite scrolling up as well as down, nor wanted to remove items on top, nor wanted to scroll by clicking on a scrollbar; if anything, you have asked to **remove** the scrollbar (`overflow:hidden` instead of `overflow:scroll`). BTW, if you click e.g. half way on the scrollbar with infinitely many items, you go halfway to infinity... What would be the meaning of reaching an item on a finite index with your use case?  I am therefore going to answer no additional questions.

Comment: Regarding `QStyledItemDelegate`, are you seriously saying you cannot see the other methods it has besides `paint`? what about `createEditor`, that returns a `QWidget`? Do you think it could perhaps answer "how to return a widget"? Once you have the editor created, simply render it in the `QPainter` parameter of `paint`; there is nothing fancy nor specific to your problem doing that, just good old plain Qt development. The *Star delegate example* (link on the page you consulted) will get you started.

Comment: @Atmo For future reference, remember that it's always better to wait for the OP to provide clarity about what they're asking before answering.

Comment: @musicamante, I can only concur... But the silver lining is that I may get to see a completely different approach if you try to tackle the question. With the extent of my humble Qt knowledge, the only way I know to avoid creating infinitely many widgets when scrolling down is with that single delegate in a view. I would love to see others' ideas on this kind of questions.

Comment: @Atmo I created a small test application using your suggestions. The problem is that the controls of only a single widget could be used at any time, if I render lets say a video in one widget and a second video in a second widget only one of them could play at any time (or I did make a mistake adapting [this tutorial](https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/pyqt5-video-widget/) only setting the video to a constant path?). Beyond that I have to trigger the call to `createEditor` by clicking, before I could use any of the controls. `QAbstractItemView::EditTrigger` do not list a hover trigger.